# In the novel "It", where exactly does Ben Hanscom live?

Tags: stephen-king, it

Maybe I haven't been giving enough attention, but I am really unaware of the location of Ben's house.

I'm in the last part of Chapter 4 of Stephen King's *It* and Ben is standing over the canal bridge where he sees It for the first time. He was returning home from school. I have checked out some maps by googling but none has his home marked on it, even though nearly everyone else's is marked.

When the Bowers gang attacks him, he was on Kansas Street, but the scene that I'm talking about (over the canal bridge) is really far away. It's not making sense to me. I really need to know his route from school.

Comment: Can’t say where his house is, but going by the map I saw, said bridge looks pretty close to Beverly Marsh's house and in the middle of downtown Derry. There’s every reason for Ben to take an "extended" route home from school (doesn’t his mother have a few jobs?).

Comment: @Pam, I understand that he has reasons to choose his routes as he does. I just want to see for myself if I'd choose those routes myself in those situations and thus gauge his intelligence, in a way. I'm a huge fantasy nerd, and geological consistency is my number one priority. Even though there is no war/escape/battle plan being hatched in IT, I am nonetheless interested in the maps... I just am.